# Can spirometry data be imported to an app through HealthKit, or do digital spirometers block access to this data?

Tags: ios, api, healthkit

I am building a lung function tracking app in Swift, and to augment qualitative inputs, it would be incredibly valuable to import FEV1 and FVC data from existing bluetooth-enabled spirometers. I see in HealthKit documentation that there exists a simple query to execute (static let forcedVitalCapacity: HKQuantityTypeIdentifie and static let forcedVitalCapacity: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier)

I have this article (https://www.natashatherobot.com/healthkit-getting-fitness-data/) from another stack exchange thread that details how to apply healthkit queries, so my fundamental question is whether this spirometry data would be blocked by existing apps from being shared to our app, or if it simply a matter of getting the User's permission to share that data.

Thank you for any and all pointers and advice, digging up APIs for each spirometry company has been a royal pain, so if HealthKit provides a viable option, this would be incredibly valuable to our patients.

I have existing, generic information about HealthKit queries, but I'd like to know if health data (especially spirometer) is ever proprietary to a single device or if it is up to user discretion

Comment: It is up to each company to decide if the data they collect goes into HealthKit or not.  I did a quick google just now and didn't find any spirometers that mention Healthkit directly. I'd like to find one, too, so post back if you find one. I'll keep looking.